# Codeigniter 4 - route now working / 404 / Controller or its method is not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Here are a couple of my routes;

This one works:

```
$routes->get('/admin/users', 'Admin/User/User_Controller::user_index');
```

This one doesn't work:

```
$routes->get('/admin/toggle_user_is_active/(:num)','Admin/User/User_Controller::toggle_user_is_active/$1');
```

As you can see, it is calling the same method.  The passed in value is a userid like 72.  If active is 1 in the db it then sets it to 0 and vice verse, thus the name toggle_user_is_active($id).

If I put directly in URL as follows:

```
https://example.com/admin/toggle_user_is_active/72
```

I get the following error:

```
404 file not found
Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Admin::index
```

The toggle in the view is as follows:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('admin/users/toggle_user_is_active/'.$user->id)?>"> Toggle </a>
```

When clicked it produces:

```
https://example.com/admin/toggle_user_is_active/72
```

Scratching my head!  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: This really is a long shot but I wonder does it help if you concentrate on the user ID to the end of the site_url() function and not within it? Like site_url('admin/users/toggle_user_is_active/').$user->id

Comment: The url is correct though.  I tried $routes->get('/admin/toggle_user_is_active', 'Admin/User/User_Controller::toggle_user_is_active/72'); and is works when hardcoded.  Puzzling.

Comment: This is the solution.  Notice the backslash.  I cannot find where in the docs it says this.  Any pointers helpful. $routes->add('/admin/toggle_user_is_active/(:any)', 'Admin\User\User_Controller::toggle_user_is_active/$1');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespaces are defined using backslashes (`\`), **not** forward slashes (`/`).

Instead of:
`'Admin/User/User_Controller::toggle_user_is_active/$1'`

Use this:
`'Admin\User\User_Controller::toggle_user_is_active/$1'`

[Name resolution rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php#language.namespaces.rules)

> Qualified name
>
> This is an identifier with a namespace separator,
> such as `Foo\Bar`

[Setting your own routing rules](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#setting-your-own-routing-rules)

> The controller and method should be listed in the same way that you
> would use a static method, by separating the **fully-namespaced
> class** and its method with a double-colon, like `Users::list`.

Answer (score 1):

see my sample code code  and edit your like me

```
<?php

/*
 * Myth:Auth routes file.
 */

$routes->group('api', ['namespace' => 'Modules\Home\Controllers'], function ($routes) {


    $routes->group('home', function ($routes) {

        $routes->get('', 'Home::index');
        $routes->get('news-list', 'Home::news');
        $routes->get('news-comment', 'Home::newsComment');
        $routes->get('news-show/(:num)', 'Home::newsShow/$1');
        $routes->get('fast-food-list', 'Home::fastFood');
        $routes->get('fast-food-comment', 'Home::fastFoodComment');
        $routes->get('fast-food-show/(:num)', 'Home::fastFoodShow/$1');
        $routes->get('setting-list', 'Home::settings');
        $routes->get('view-list', 'Home::views');
        $routes->get('advertisement-list', 'Home::advertisements');

        $routes->get('visitor-save', 'Home::visitor');
        $routes->post('contact-save', 'Home::contact');

    });
});
```